# Opening tab with anchor link

Tags: jquery, tabs, anchor

I have some typical tab content and I really need some help. I would like to achieve, that when user tries to get to a specific tab via external anchor link (http://www.url.com#content2), the navigation link becomes activated and the correct tab is shown.

Thank you for your help.

HTML

```
<nav class="inner-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#content1">Inner nav navigation link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#content2">Inner nav navigation link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#content3">Inner nav navigation link3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<section class="tab-content" id="content1">
    <article>
        content1 goes here
    </article>
</section>

<section class="tab-content" id="content2">
    <article>
        content2 goes here
    </article>
</section>

<section class="tab-content" id="content3">
    <article>
        content3 goes here
    </article>
</section>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".tab-content").hide();
    $(".tab-content:first").show();
    $(".inner-nav li:first").addClass("active");

    $(".inner-nav a").click(function(){
        $(".inner-nav li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        var currentTab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").hide();
        $(currentTab).show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

I have a live example [here](http://kajag.com/themes/book_your_travel/location.html) 
So, if you click on the navigation, everything works ok, but if you want to go to a specific tab kajag.com/themes/book_your_travel/location.html#sports_and_nature the correct tab does not open.

Comment: are you getting any error??

Comment: What seems to be the problem, works fine in this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hBKuu/) ??

Comment: No, this javascript works just fine if the user is clicking the navigation links. However, if the user tries to open a specific tab via external anchor link, the .js doesn't work.

Comment: I apologize, I wasn't specific enough.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could solve this by simply checking the hash when the page loads, and then trigger a click on the right tab, like so:

```
$(function () {
    $(".tab-content").hide().first().show();
    $(".inner-nav li:first").addClass("active");

    $(".inner-nav a").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('li').addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        $($(this).attr('href')).show().siblings('.tab-content').hide();
    });

    var hash = $.trim( window.location.hash );

    if (hash) $('.inner-nav a[href$="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just finished something similar here (disclosure, my site): http://kronia.com.au/#showcase

Since you're not using the hash directly (i.e. the page shouldn't scroll to a div, it should hide/show a tab depending on the value) you need to check first for a hash (there may not be a hash in the link).

```
if (window.location.hash){
  someFunction();
}
```

Then show/hide tabs based on the value of the hash. If you're performing some transition, then define a 'from' and 'to' tab, otherwise just the tab that should be shown. E.g.:

```
function someFunction(_to, _from){
    _to.removeClass('kr-dormant').addClass('kr-next');
    _from.removeClass('kr-current').addClass('kr-dormant');
    _to.removeClass('kr-next').addClass('kr-current');
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I am not sure if this would be the optimal solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exactly behavior that you will have if you use [JQuery UI Tabs](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/) widget

See these examples :

- To default tab : https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/default.html
- To second tab : https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/default.html#tabs-2
- To third tab : https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/tabs/default.html#tabs-3

The example code of implementation :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```