# Javascript navigation external link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help again. I have a ribbon that holds navigation. It doesn't really do anything, it just "toggles" the links from active/visible which is ok. However, I would like to achieve that if the user clicks on the External link (the third li in profile-nav in the example) it takes him to the url in the link. Thank you very much!

HTML:

```
<div class="ribbon">
    <nav>
        <ul class="profile-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#" title="My Account">My Account</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" title="Login">Login</a></li>
              <li><a href="http://www.google.com" title="External link">External link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="lang-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" title="English (US)">English (US)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="English (UK)">English (UK)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Deutsch">Deutsch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Italiano">Italiano</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Русский">Русский</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="currency-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" title="$US Dollar">$US Dollar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="€ Euro">€ Euro</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="£ Pound">£ Pound</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ribbon li').hide();
    $('.ribbon li.active').show();
    $(".ribbon li a").click(function() {
        $(".ribbon li").hide();
        if ($(this).parent().parent().hasClass('open'))
            $(this).parent().parent().removeClass('open');
        else {
            $(".ribbon ul").removeClass('open');
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass('open');
        }
        $(this).parent().siblings().each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $(this).parent().attr('class', 'active'); 
        $('.ribbon li.active').show();
        $('.ribbon ul.open li').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of achieve what you want. Following your approach, I would suggest adding a `class="nolink"` to the anchor you don't need to follow an external link. After that bind the click event to the corresponding "a.nolink".

The HTML would look as follows:

```
<div class="ribbon">
    <nav>
        <ul class="profile-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#" class="nolink" title="My Account">My Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="nolink" title="Login">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.google.com" title="External link">External link</a>            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="lang-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" class="nolink" title="English (US)">English (US)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nolink" title="English (UK)">English (UK)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nolink" title="Deutsch">Deutsch</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nolink" title="Italiano">Italiano</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nolink" title="Русский">Русский</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="currency-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" class="nolink" title="$US Dollar">$US Dollar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nolink" title="€ Euro">€ Euro</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="nolink" title="£ Pound">£ Pound</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And the javascript to bind your elements:

```
$(".ribbon li a.nolink").click(function() { ...
```

Comment: You are welcome. If that really help you please mark the as the correct answer (In the check next to my reply). You should do the same with the other question [you posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678511/opening-tab-with-anchor-link). Stackoverflow is a reputation community and doing that helps me as well as you. Cheers.