# Open specific tab on another page with ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

I have a webforms website and I am using Bootstrap.  I have a few links in my footer that will link to various tabs on different pages.  My problem is that no matter what tab I specify the link to open, they only load the page with the default tab.

I've done this several times with static sites, but never with ASP.NET.  I believe the problem lies with ASP.NET adding the .aspx to the end of each page.

Here is what I tried:

```
<a href="/Personal-Banking.aspx#checking">Checking Accounts</a>
```

So, the page I'm linking to is Personal-Banking.aspx and the Id of the tab I'm wanting to open is #checking.  All this is doing now is opening the Personal-Banking page and opening the default tab, which is different than the #checking tab.

I've tried removing the .aspx but it still does not open correctly and the images are all broken.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: think you're gonna need to do something similar to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678511/opening-tab-with-anchor-link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code used to get linking to tabs to work in asp.net webforms:

```
<!--Update this to reflect tabs on this page-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
            if (/pipe/.test(loc)) {
                $('.pipe').addClass('active');
                $('#pipe').addClass('active');
            }
            else if (/manholes/.test(loc)) {
                $('.manholes').addClass('active');
                $('#manholes').addClass('active');
            }
            else if (/fittings/.test(loc)) {
                $('.fittings').addClass('active');
                $('#fittings').addClass('active');
            }
            else if (/tanks/.test(loc)) {
                $('.tanks').addClass('active');
                $('#tanks').addClass('active');
            }
            else {
                $('.pipe').addClass('active');
                $('#pipe').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the page that you link to, look at the source of the webpage on your browser when you get to it.  Is the `ID` of that tab really `"checking"`, or is it something else like `"MainContent_TabbedPanel_checking"`?

Don't look at your code, look at what your browser is getting.

Comment: The url when hovering of that tab is Personal-Banking#checking

Comment: Have you tried having an anchor in each tab you are linking to?  Linking to a page with a # link, only works if that page has an anchor with that id.  Inside the checking tab of the receiving page, try putting <a id="checkinganchor" />, then change your link to go to "Personal-Banking.aspx#checkinganchor".  I am not sure if that will actually open the tab, but give it a shot.

Comment: That's what i currently have as posted in the original post.  Thanks

Comment: What you said in your original post is that you are linking to the id of the tab.  Not the id of an anchor within the tab.  Different things.

Comment: Maybe my mistake.  I am reading "tabs" and thinking tabs within a tabbed panel.  If by tab you meant anchor, and that is not working, then you have a different problem from what I was understanding.  Sorry.