# Twitter Bootstrap Tabs: Open Specific Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have the following code which works great as tabs - however, I'd like it if I visit *`www.mysite.com/#female`* that the Female tab becomes active and displays content in the Female tab pane.

How do I achieve this? As you can see, I have made an attempt with my code but this has failed.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/2yocpy2k/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots">
    <meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="googlebot">
    <base href="https://fiddle.jshell.net/2yocpy2k/show/light/">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-compat-git.js" type=
    "text/javascript">
    </script>
    <link href="/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/css/result-light.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <link href=
    "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel=
    "stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style type="text/css">
    /* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

    /* Optional theme */
    @import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

    body {
    margin: 10px;
    }
    </style>
    <title>Bootstrap 3 Template</title>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
    $(window).on('load', function() {
    /* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */

    // Javascript to enable link to tab
    var url = document.location.toString();
    if (url.match('#')) {
    $('.nav-tabs li h2 a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
    } 

    // Change hash for page-reload
    $('.nav-tabs li h2 a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
    })
    });//]]> 

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>and</p>
        <p>Welcome!</p>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li>
                <h2><a data-target="#female" data-toggle="tab">Female</a></h2>
            </li>
            <li>
                <h2><a data-target="#male" data-toggle="tab">Male</a></h2>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="female">
                Open Female
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="male">
                Open Male
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678511/opening-tab-with-anchor-link any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that adds the active class when a hash exists on page load.  Include it in your top script section like so:

```
$(function () {
    var hashTab = window.location.hash;
    if (hashTab != '') {
        $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hashTab + '"]').tab('show');
        $(hashTab).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - however, when I try this, I get `jquery-git.js:1586 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .nav-tabs a[href=#female]` error.

Comment: Changing it to `$('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hashTab + '"]').tab('show');` resolved this :-)

Comment: Final question - how do I set the `li` to have an active class. Currently it doesn't do this despite showing the correct tab pane :)

Comment: I think something like $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hashTab + '"]').parent().addClass('active'); should work.

Comment: I've tried this but unfortunately it didn't work. No errors in the console either :(

Comment: Ops, I didn't notice your H2 elements.  I think you'd have to do the parent of the parent or swap out .parent() for .closest('li')

Comment: I'll maybe keep this for another question - I'm also trying to push the user down to that part of the page and that's proving to be quite tricky too :-) Thanks for all your help, eric g :)