# javascript: Resolving deeplinking issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, deep-linking, hashchange

I have a tab component say in a HTML strcture

```
 <ul>
     <li><a id='tab1' href='/url#tab1'> Tab1 </a></li>
     <li><a id='tab2' href='/url#tab2'> Tab2 </a></li>
     <li><a id='tab3' href='/url#tab3'> Tab3 </a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class='tab-content'>
     content of respective div loaded on click.
    </div>
```

Here the content of the respective TAB as the click handlers are in place for that and its working fine without any 
problems. The click handler looks like

```
$('#tab2').click(function() {
  //show tab2 content.
});
```

Now, I have to support deeplinking so that , when user comes through URL : http://url#tab2, need to show respective tab content. So for this,
my approach is to use 'hashchange' event , which will read hash params and load the content based on the hash value.

The query or the pain is , woundn't it cause a conflict between click event on a and  hash change event?

What should be the appropriate way of resolving deepliking in this case ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678511/opening-tab-with-anchor-link

Comment: shouldn't need click event handler if you listen to hash change

Comment: @charlietfl : Yes I agree but the problem is I have click handlers already in place and there is whole business logic in it. I can't simply revert. Is there any way that I keep the same click handler and implement linking on top of it ?

Comment: link above would do it and you wouldn't listen to hash change for it then

Comment: Why don't you only read `document.location.hash` when the page loads instead of using the event?

Comment: Thanks @axel.michel for pointing to the thread. I will plan to implement the solution.