# How do I link a button to a tab with div content on another page?

Tags: html, button, tabs

[This is what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Kk5.jpg)
I wish to link a button to show content relating to a certain div in a tab on another page, how can I do this using JQuery?
I have included a picture / drawing so that you can understand what I mean.

```
<div class="myTabs">
   <ul class="tabs" data-tab data-options="deep_linking:true">
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#One">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Two">Tab 2</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="tabContent">
   <div id="One">This is the content in div one on Tab 1</div>
   <div id="AnotherOne">This is the content is second div on Tab 1</div>
</div>
```

So two.html has a button that must link directly to show content in one.html, Tab 1, div One & the second button must link to one.html, Tab 1, second div, i.e.'AnotherOne'

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening tab with anchor link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678511/opening-tab-with-anchor-link)

Comment: Ok, shared some code.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a hash value to the link on two.html and add a startup script to the page with the tabs to show/hide the div that you need.

```
<a href='/two.html#one'>BUTTON ONE</a>
<a href='/two.html#two'>BUTTON TWO</a>
```

On one.html you can add a startup script that sets the visibility of the correct div. If your tab contains two divs like this (Everything hidden by default?):

```
<div class='one' style='display:none;'>div one</div>
<div class='two' style='display:none;'>div two</div>
```

You can add the following startup script to two.html:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   // If the location is empty show the content of div one?
   var tab = window.location.hash ?? 'one';

   $('div.' + tab).show()
});
</script>
```

Comment: HI, thank you for your feedback.  All content in all divs on all the tabs are visible by default.  Refreshing the page shows tab one by default. Just need to be able to reference the content in tab one & and div 1 to link directly.  Let me try this code and see if it works.

Comment: Do you mean just scolling to the right position on the page? You can use the hash for that as well, but add the following anchor tag to your divs: <div><a name='one'></a>div one</div> and <div><a name='two'></a>div one</div>

Comment: Yes, I added some code that I have at present, maybe that may shed some light?

Comment: I guess your tabs navigation and the anchor navigation might be a problem in this case because they both rely on the hash value. Are you using Bootstrap for your tabs? Have you actually tried adding the <a name='xyz'></a> to the divs inside your tab and adding that hash to the buttons? If that doesn't work, please create a plunker and I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can do is using anchor tag.If you are using button wrap it by a anchor tag.

Here is the code.

```
<a href="page2.html#elementID"><button>Jump</button></a>
```