# How to set response.sendRedirect to a particular tab on a jsp page

Tags: jsp, response.redirect

I have a jsp page named as index2.jsp . This page has 4 tabs named as "Account Registration", "Application Registration", "License Calculator" and "Report Module". I want to set the response.sendRedirect of a particular button to the "Report Module" tab. However, I am unable to do it. I have to set it to index2.jsp by the code response.sendRedirect("index2.jsp"); . How can I set it to the "Report Module" tab? Please help.

Comment: have you tried with `response.sendRedirect("index2.jsp?tab=report")` and then use js to select this tab?

Answer (score 0):

You should [hash](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) property :

> Return the anchor part of a URL.

You can do something like this.

1. In your Controller redirect to the correct tab

`response.sendRedirect("index2.jsp#report_module");`

2. In your jsp file show the corresponding tab

**index2.jsp**

```
<script>
$(function () {
var hash = $.trim( window.location.hash );

if (hash) $('.your-css-selector a[href$="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click');

});
</script>
```

I've take information from this answer [Opening tab with anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678511/opening-tab-with-anchor-link).